# Cmake Directory Error

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake, ros

I'm trying to catkinize autonomy labs' AR drone ROS package.  When I run `catkin_make` I get this error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package libsdl-dev.

Set libsdl-dev_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
for libsdl-dev.  The file will have one of the following names:

    libsdl-devConfig.cmake
    libsdl-dev-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
ardrone_autonomy/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

I've searched for both files and I cannot locate them.  Where can I find them or download them?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This means that libsdl-dev is not installed on your computer. For ubuntu the package is available as libsdl1.2-dev.

The homepage of libsdl is [here](http://www.libsdl.org/).

Comment: I tried to install it with ```sudo apt-get install``` and is said that the package was up to date.  I don't think I need the whole package, just the cmake file.  Do you know where the file is installed on my computer?

Comment: Try to give this flag to CMake: `-Dlibsdl-dev_DIR=/usr/lib` or the path where libsdl-dev is installed.